# Regex to strip phpdoc multiline comment

Tags: regex, comments, phpdoc, strip

I have this:

```
/**
 * @file
 * API for loading and interacting with modules.
 * More explaination here.
 *
 * @author  Reveller <me@localhost>
 * @version 19:05 28-12-2008
 */
```

I'm looking for a regex to strip all but the @token data, so the result would be:

```
@file API for loading and interacting with modules. More explaination here.
@author Reveller <me@localhost>
@version 19:05 28-12-2008
```

I now have this:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\r?\n *\* */', ' ', $text);
```

It does the job partially: it only removes the * in front of each line. Who could help me so it also strips /** and the final slash /? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S: If, for instance, the commentlbock would contain something like

```
/**
 * @foo Here's some slashes for ya: / and \
 */
```

Then obviously the slashes after @foo may not be stripped. The reult would have to be:

```
@foo Here's some slashes for ya: / and \
```

I hope there's a regex guru out there :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$result = preg_replace('%(\r?\n(?! \* ?@))?^(/\*\*\r?\n \* | \*/| \* ?)%m', ' ', $subject);
```

It will insert an extra space at the start of each line, so you might want to strip leading whitespace in a second step.

Explanation:

`(\r?\n(?! \* ?@))?`: If possible, match a newline unless it's followed by `* @`

`^`: Assert that the following match starts at the beginning of the line

`(`: Either match

`/\*\*\r?\n \*`: `/**<newline> *`

`|` or

`\*/`: `*/`

`|`: or

`\* ?`: `*`, optionally followed by another space

`)`: End of alternation sequence

Comment: Wow, thanks! It works like a charm :-) Trimming whitespace is no problem.

Comment: @Reveller, if this solved your problem, you should mark the answer as accepted, and perhaps upvote it as well.

Comment: Done and done :-) Thanks for telling me. I'm new here and didn't know you could do that.