# Remove entirely PHPDoc from all files / or this file?

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

Is it possible to delete/remove all PHPDoc from all files or File that we are working on?

[image]

I mean this things and all other comments like that PHPDoc etc

Comment: Why exactly do you want to remove them? They are useful for self-documenting + providing typehints (for IDE to offer correct methods on objects/verify acceptable values for parameters etc). Framework itself relies on them (in some places, like DI). But ion any case: no -- if you wish to actually physically remove them you will have to do it manually or by some special tool. The best IDE can do for you here is to fold them so each of them occupy only one line.

Comment: They affect really bad my personal readability, it makes also highlighting errors on change parameters etc... iritating for me, doesn't help me at all, just makes me feel bad, etc

Comment: @LazyOne at least I want to delete them from my files, controllers. But I how to do it at one click or something?

Comment: As I have said -- there is no known to me way to do that (to quickly remove them). As far as I'm aware IDE simply does not have such functionality -- usually people asking other way around (how to quickly generate such comments/how to use typehints properly so they help in code completion etc). The only thing right now I can think of -- use regex Find and Replace...

Comment: @LazyOne waste that this is not built in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options to consider:

- You can use some **find and replace** function of your IDE that supports regular expression, or a php program using preg_replace: see [Regex to strip phpdoc multiline comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749642/regex-to-strip-phpdoc-multiline-comment)
- You can use tokenizer or other PHP library for processing source code processing: see [Best way to automatically remove comments from PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code)
- You can use `php -w` to remove comments and whitespaces and then a PHP formatter in your IDE to produce readable code.
- And some other options: see [Best way to automatically remove comments from PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code)

Comment: waste that this is not built in

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, now have a rule in the inspection section: File > Settings > Inspections, then PHPDoc and finally Redundant PHPDoc comment. I changed it to a Weak Warning first, then went to one of the classes I had the issue and ran Code > Inspect Code, only on that file. Click on Analyse.

A panel of Inspection results will show up and Redundant PHPDoc comment, will show in PHP > PHPDoc section. Click on it, and on the right side, you will have another button "Run inspection on ...". That will run an inspection ONLY for that rule. Click on it and choose a custom scope or the whole project. Click Ok.

Now the inspection results will show all occurrences of that case. You can click on the first file on the left panel and SHIFT + click the last one and finally click the "Remove redundant PHPDoc comment" button on the right panel.

Not really intuitive, but did the trick for me.